# Font to use in iOS social network application

Tags: fonts, iphone

I am almost in the final step of the design of a social network application, I am just not sure what would be the best **font** type for that type of applications, instead of using the system font type.

Comment: Probably it is better to show some screenshot or example... and tell us for what platform do you built the app - mobile or desktop etc. Most of the social apps use SANS SERIFs

Comment: @Ilan Its a general question actually, I didn't do anything yet because I am not sure what is the name of the type that I will use basically. and I am using Xcode as the platform and the programming language is Objective C and its for mobile users so yes its for iPhone users iOS7 and if you would like to know more I am using a storyboard.

Comment: Welcome! "Best" is subjective as well as being highly dependent upon many other factors. There's no way anyone can determine what's "best" for your project without seeing and knowing more about the project. And even the, it boils down to a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Scott Well thats correct if the font type are listed upon the best and worse I think there won't be million of fonts online, but I was just trying to know the people opinion. as what would be the best option for my application and I already wrote a brief about it its actually a social network application, and usually social network application target all users. Thanks Scott ^_^

Comment: Hi Lolieta. Stack exchange sites aren't like other sites you may be familiar with. The idea behind all Stack Exchange sites, including GD.SE, is a strict Question <> Answer format. Questions are expected to have answers which can be supported by facts, resources, and other determining factors. While we do allow some more subjective questions here, simply asking for opinions of others is exceptionally off-topic. A list of users all spouting off what *they simply prefer* won't help anyone.

Comment: The notion that your question is off-topic, is merely my opinion. And my opinion alone does not carry a great deal of weight. However, you may find other users agree with me and also vote to put your question "on hold". If you can reword the question with an edit so that answers can be definitive rather than opinion-based, you may find you get much better answers.

Comment: @Scott I am sorry :( but thanks anyway

Comment: No need to be sorry for anything!! I'm just trying to help you get better results, that's all.

Comment: @Scott you're awesome ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is just general, I suggest using SANS-SERIF font available on the iphone.

i.e. we used html as a help file -

[image]

in xCode iphone simulator -

[image]

[Here](http://www.iphoneruler.net/tag/ios-7/) you have examples of the fonts used in iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Fira Sans is a Typeface created by Eric Spiekermann  for Mozilla for web applications. It is a free Typeface. Here is the link:

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/products/firefox-os/typeface/

There is a style guide at this link too.